# Saving an Editable object to file

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

How can I save an Editable object like `mEditText.getText();` to a file?
I have tried with the following code and it works but at the end I get an `IOException` and `IOException.getLocalizedMessage();` and `IOException.getMessage();` both displays the following String.

```
E/Error:(5223): android.text.SpannableStringBuilder
```

Here is the code I tried with:

```
      try {                                                                                             
      SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(mMainEditText.getText());

      //Create a File object with user entered file name...
      File outputFile = new File(getDocStorageFolder(),
              mUserEnterFileName
              + ".msd");

      Log.e("Path:", "" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());        
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); //create your FileOutputStream here                      

      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
      oos.writeObject(ssb);
      oos.close();
      oos.flush();
      fos.close();                                              

      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();      
      Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
      Log.e("Error: ", e.getLocalizedMessage());
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occured while "
              + "attempting to create the Document file!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Comment: Nothing related to Android's spanned-string logic supports `Serializable`.

Comment: Thank you. So, can you suggest some other possibility to do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly save an `Editable`, or a `SpannableStringBuilder`, to a file.

You are welcome to convert the *contents* of a `Spanned` into something that you can write into a file. I am not aware of anything that covers all possible spans, in large part because anyone can invent their own.

`Html.toHtml()` in the Android SDK will take a subset of spans and generate HTML from them.

Also, [my CWAC-RichEdit library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit) contains [a `SpannedXhtmlGenerator`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit#usage-xhtml-conversion) which converts a different subset of spans into XHTML, designed to be read back in using `SpannableStringGenerator` from the same library.

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richedit
seems very helpful, let me check it out.